# IBM worklight v5.0.6 - App center client fails to connect to the server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I installed worklight application center v5.0.6 on a Linux system. I used Liberty profile with the following property:
worklight application center URL:
http://{host}:9080/appcenterconsole/applications/Appplications.html

I am able to install the Installer on my android and IOS device using this URL:
http://{host}:9080/appcenterconsole/installers.html

However, when I run the "IBM App Center" client, I got `failed to connect to the server` error with the following setting input:

username: appcenteradmin
pass: mypass

server: {host}:9080/appcenterconsole/applications
SSL: OFF

Can anyone help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: Have you also set this username and password anywhere? By default the cerdentials are demo/demo. Are you sure the host is the right one?

Comment: Hi, Yes. I'm sure that I connect to the right host. I even tried the default credential: demo/demo. But I still got the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

The IBM App Center Client does not connect to appcenterconsole, it connects to the "Application Center Services", i.e. to applicationcenter.

Try as server: {host}:9080/applicationcenter

Example: 192.168.178.42:9080/applicationcenter

Details:

{host}:{port}/appcenterconsole  is the Administration Console. You use this when you want to upload applications via browser. This is just the HTML frontent that you see in the browser.

{host}:{port}/applicationcenter are the REST services. They do the real work. The HTML frontend connect to the REST services automatically to do the real work. The Mobile Client does not need a "HTML frontend" since it is a mobile application that has its own GUI, hence it needs to connect to the REST services, not to the appcenterconsole.